# Is there a way to prevent var=$(foo | grep bar) from causing set -e to exit my script?

Tags: bash

I would like to add an ip route in case it does not exist. To do so, I execute the following:

```
set -e
output=$(ip route | cut -d" " -f1 | grep $ip_range)
if [ -z "$output" ]; then
ip route add $ip_range dev br-int
fi
```

However, as I learnt, if grep does not find anything it exits with status 1 which ends the script due to set -e. I thought about using:

```
set +e
```

before the line which does grep (note that there is code between set -e and the line which does grep but I removed it for simplicity). However, I thought that is a bit ugly. Isn't there another way?

Comment: [Just don't use `set -e`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: If you put the conditional into the `if`, this would make it a *checked* conditional, and `set -e` doesn't apply to those anyhow.

Comment: ...`if foo | grep -q bar; then ...` is more efficient than `baz=$(foo | grep bar); if [ -z "$baz" ]; ...` anyhow -- `grep` can exit and return immediately when it sees a match instead of needing to read the rest of its input.

Comment: btw, it's not grep returning zero but returning **nonzero** that's your problem. 0 is success.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `set -e` and use `grep -q`:

```
if ! ip route | cut -d " " -f1 | grep -q "$ip_range"; then
   ip route add $ip_range dev br-int
fi
```

[Why `set -e` should be avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

There are some chances that `ip_route` may fail as well so you can use:

```
set -o pipefail
if ! ip route | cut -d " " -f1 | grep -q "$ip_range"; then
   ip route add $ip_range dev br-int
fi
```

Comment: Removing `set -e` is not feasible in this example since that would leave the `ip route` command without a success-check. If you remove `set -e` you need to check the return value of `ip route`

Comment: Use of `set -e` isn't recommended anyway. If needed, commands can be checked for exit status separately.

Comment: Yes that's true but you cannot remove `-e` without checking the return value of `ip route`. Why don't you simply add that check to demonstrate that?

Comment: In system programming *every* return type needs to get checked.  Period. (Actually I would apply that to any kind of programming, not just system programming) The `ip` commands can return 3 different return values: 0 on success, 1 on syntax error, 2 if the kernel reports an error. A simple possible kernel error would be that the device does not exist, let's say the network card is broken or the cable is not properly connected.

Comment: Before you think I'm over-pedantic, I don't say that a proper error handling needs to be part of any SO answer but this question is especially focusing on error handling and I guess the OP had the `set -e` there for a reason.

Comment: Relevant link of pitfalls of not using `set -e` was already there but I've added in answer as well.

Comment: Good! I'm still missing a check for the return value of the `ip route` command inside the conditional. I would expect it to be there when the question is about error handling.

Comment: *nod* -- adding a `|| exit` would bring us into parity with the intended behavior from using `set -e`; `ip route add` most certainly can fail.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I've added your helpful tip in answer.

Comment: Err -- I didn't mean in the pipeline component; for that, we'd want `set -o pipefail`. (Listing the routing table *can* also fail, depending on process capabilities)

Comment: Thanks, yes adding `set -o pipefail` will be handly. Now we don't need `|| exit 1` as well.

Comment: @anubhava you need to place the `|| exit 1` after the `ip route` command in order to be conform with `set -e`

Comment: And won't we need same after `cut` command also? I thought `pipefail` will not require it in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a command at the end that always returns 0.

```
$ output=$(ip route | cut -d" " -f1 | grep $ip_range ; exit 0) ; echo $?
0
```

Comment: `true` instead of `exit 0` might be the better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$(ip route | cut -d" " -f1 | (grep $ip_range || true))`. That is run `grep` in a sub shell and use `||` (or) to run a command if grep exists with non-zero, in this case `true`, so that the whole sub shell returns zero.

Comment: The answer is correct but "Try to use ..." is not an explanation. Would you consider adding one?

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to put the `|| true` outside of the pipeline? `output=$(ip route | cut -d" " -f1 | grep $ip_range) || true`.

Comment: @hek2mgl yes good point, i've added an explanation now. enough detail?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yeah that works too. i kind of like to be explicit of which command i want to ignore exit code for

Comment: The code you have here is actually less efficient than the suggestion by @griourf_gniourf, since it's creating an extra subshell. Aren't the subshells needed for the pipe enough? That said, you could replace it with `... | { grep $ip_range || true; }` to avoid the extra one, if you're really attached to this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative to `grep` and `cut` would be to use `awk` here since `awk` will return `0`regardless of if something has been printed or not:

```
output=$(ip route | awk -v ip_range="${ip_range}" '$1==ip_range{print $1}')
```